# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Trying to test my `WebSecurityAdapterConfig.class` in spring... the compiler requested that inject `filterChainproxy` but after creating a bean for `springSecurityFilterChain()` it returns Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field `springSecurityFilterChain`

code:

```java
@Configuration
@Conditional(ProdStagingCondition.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityAdapterConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

........

  @Bean(name = "springSecurityFilterChain")
  public FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain() throws ServletException, Exception {

    final List<SecurityFilterChain> listOfFilterChains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
    // listOfFilterChains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login"), new NoSecurityFilter()));

    listOfFilterChains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/docs")));

    final FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy = new FilterChainProxy(listOfFilterChains);

    return filterChainProxy;
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebSecurityAdapterConfig.class)
public class WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest {


 @Autowired
 private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
 @Autowired
 private WebApplicationContext context;

 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
   mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
      .webAppContextSetup(context)
      .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
      .alwaysDo(print())
      .apply(springSecurity())
      .build();
  }

  @Test
  public void config() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
        .perform(get("/docs"))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
  }
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.connectar.wallet.config.WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'springSecurityFilterChain'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Your configuration is conditional, how should we know if ProdStagingCondition ist met?

Comment: could that be a reason for the error?

Comment: sure, if it evalutes to false, no bean is created

Comment: @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    String springEnviroment = System.getProperty("SPRING_ENV", "development");
    return springEnviroment.equalsIgnoreCase("staging")
        || springEnviroment.equalsIgnoreCase("production");
  }

Comment: and my SPRING_ENV is development......... meaning it evalutes to false

Comment: `@SpringBootTest(classes = ...) `is for Spring Boot application to start up in tests. Try `@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebSecurityAdapterConfig.class)` instead.

Comment: @Turo.....i tried changing the SPRING_ENV for it to evaluate to true but its still failed

Comment: @humbaba..... i changed it but it still didn't work

Comment: Well, what does it mean it did not work? It should be failing with another reason. You should get `A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.` error message. You can't override it. But probably you can configure it.

Comment: what i mean by it didn't work is that the problem still persists

Comment: @Turo...... what i did now was to remove Conditional(ProdStagingCondition.class)....and now it is creating the bean.... but with that the security constraint will be enforced in all of the environments and we don't want that

Comment: Generally you sholdn't be defining a bean for the `FilterChainProxy` in your configuration, as Spring Security adds that based on the different `configure` methods. What is it you are trying to achieve? Also your `@SpringBootTest` should ideally start your application and not just a subset (like you are doing now). You should also `@Autowired` the `MockMvc` because that is added for you, with all the security (or not) preconfigured.

Comment: thank you @M.Deinum.... like i said the reason why i am having all the problem is the Conditional. annotation.... Now i need to be able to use the annotation and still be able to test my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: I'm arguing that you actually need that annotation and using the wrong tool to achieve what you want. However as it isn't fully clear what you want/try to achieve I cannot answer that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Removed  `@Conditional(ProdStagingCondition.class)` from the WebSecurityAdapterConfig class

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(ProdStagingCondition.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```