# how to write test for WebSecurityAdapterConfig with @Conditional

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to write test for WebSecurityAdapterConfig class with @Conditional annotation that allows us to enforce security constraints based on the enviroment we are running the app.... initially i couldn't test the class until i discovered from ([Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'springSecurityFilterChain'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157136/unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-field-springsecurityfilterchain)) that 
@Conditional(ProdStagingCondition.class) annotation is what is preventing the test from running

code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Conditional(ProdStagingCondition.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityAdapterConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private JWT jwt;
  private RequiredEnvironmentVariables requiredEnvironmentVariables;
  private JWTAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;
  private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  public WebSecurityAdapterConfig() {
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to store user's state.
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // authorization requests config
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()

        // Any other request must be authenticated
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        // handle an authorized attempts
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
        .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        .addFilterAfter(
            new JWTokenAuthenticationFilter(
                jwt, RequiredEnvironmentVariables.supportedPaymentClients),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebSecurityAdapterConfig.class)
public class WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext context;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc =MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .alwaysDo(print())
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
  }

  @Test
  public void config() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
        .perform(get("/docs"))
        .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
  }
}
```

error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.

```
at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.beforeMockMvcCreated(SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.AbstractMockMvcBuilder.build(AbstractMockMvcBuilder.java:136)
at com.connectar.wallet.config.WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest.setUp(WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Can you try declaring bean for ProdStagingCondition in your test configuration?

Comment: please how do i go about that?

Comment: Create a class with `@TestConfiguration` annotation and declare the bean using `@Bean` inside that classs. Let's say `SecurityTestConfiguration` is your class name.. After that, add `@Import(SecurityTestConfiguration.class)` on your `WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest` class

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by finding a way to set different environment property for different tests so i added @TestPropertySource(properties = {"SPRING_ENV= production"}) like this:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"SPRING_ENV= production"})
@SpringBootTest()
public class WebSecurityAdapterConfigUnitTest {
```

and then i changed my ProdStagingCondition class

from:

```
public class ProdStagingCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    String springEnviroment = System.getProperty("SPRING_ENV", "development");
    return springEnviroment.equalsIgnoreCase("staging")
        || springEnviroment.equalsIgnoreCase("production");
  }
}
```

to:

```
public class ProdStagingCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    String springEnviroment = System.getProperty("SPRING_ENV", "development");
    return System.getProperty("SPRING_ENV") != "development";


  }
}
```

Comment: You could have used spring profiles with `@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "production")`
and made your `ProdStagingCondition` use the profile. That would be way cleaner.

Comment: thank you  @SunilChakravarthy actually we have SPRING_PROFILES and SPRINN_ENV properties........ the SPRING_PROFILE specifies which of the profiles